# Image caches drops when external css URL changes

Tags: css, caching, static

Recently I hashed my URL's based on the file contents and found this issue.

Take an example where in "**style1.css**" I have defined a list of images using "background-image" whose URL's are also hashed based on the image file contents.

Style.css

```
.class1{
 background-image: url("../../image1.hash.png");
}

.class2{
 background-image: url("../../image2.hash.png");
}
```

Initial requests for **style1.css** hash to a URL like **style1.hash1.css** every URL request is of 200 Status.

When the CSS file **style1.css** is changed, the hash changes to **style1.hash2.css**, which is correct behaviour.

So style1.css will be reloaded with 200. But what puzzles me is that **every image url defined withing that css is also reloaded even if their URL's remains unchanged**.

Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Are the images requested and return a 304 response?

Comment: No the images are returned with 200 status. @cuberoot

Comment: Do you have a public url for me to see exactly what's going on?

Comment: @cuberoot I have a public URL but can't disclose it publicly. I can private message you but cant get your contact info through your account. My contact information is available through my github account "https://github.com/jpsam7"